# Turn off Hyphenation in Illustrator globally

Tags: adobe-illustrator, hyphenation

Adobe Illustrator CC likes to force hyphenation on every single piece of text. It used to be possible in earlier versions to switch it off globally for new documents through the Paragraph palette option when no documents were open. In Illustrator CC, this has no effect though.

Is this a bug, or did they hide it even better?

Answer (score 1):

The "no document open" thing has never worked in Illustrator - I believe you may be thinking of Indesign there. In Illustrator, with no document open, there are *no* paragraph or character styles even available.

You have to edit the [Basic Paragraph] paragraph style in the **Document Profiles** for Illustrator - the startup files.

Here's Adobe's rundown on editing startup files: http://blogs.adobe.com/adobeillustrator/2009/05/startup_profiles_a_great_tool.html